# Extraction of data from Flickr

Tags: java, performance, parsing, xml

I'm crawling Flickr for data for my university research project. However it's very slow and I'm not sure what it is exactly.  It could be the `FileWriter` slowing it down. Any advice on speeding it up?

```
try {

    String userID = file.getUserIDFromList(i);

    System.out.println(i + "." + " " + userID);//to screen

    String urlString = "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicGroups&api_key=myAPIKey&user_id=" + userID;
    System.out.println(urlString);
    //print userID to file
    file.writeGroupID(userID);
    Collection<Group> groupNames = people.getPublicGroups(userID);

    String groupCount = Integer.toString(groupNames.size());
    //write number of groups to the file
    file.writeFile(groupCount);

    Iterator<Group> iteratorDetails = groupNames.iterator();
    //iterate over list to get each group's details

    while (iteratorDetails.hasNext()) {
        Group groupName = (Group)iteratorDetails.next();

        //get group name
        String name = groupName.getName();

        //get group id
        String id = groupName.getId();

        GroupsInterface groupInter = flickr.getGroupsInterface();

        Group gInfo = groupInter.getInfo(id);

        DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = b.parse(urlString);

        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("group");
        Node n = items.item(poolCounter);
        Element e = (Element) n;

        //get total photos in group
        String numberOfPhotos = e.getAttribute("pool_count");
        //get members in the group
        int numberOfMembers = gInfo.getMembers();

        //write group details to file
        file.writeFile("\t" + name + " " + numberOfPhotos + " photos" + ", " + numberOfMembers + " members");
        System.out.println("\t" + name + " " + numberOfPhotos + " photos" + ", " + numberOfMembers + " members");
        poolCounter++;
    }
    file.newLine();
}
```

Comment: Your code is broken, buggy, or confusing. Why do you have just one URL `urlString` defined as `"https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicGroups&api_key=myAPIKey&user_id=" + userID` but then you repeatedly re-parse it inside the group-loop? What value does that add?

Comment: Interestingly, the `<group>` elements returned from the `flickr.people.getPublicGroups` REST method contain a `pool_count` attribute ([example](https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicGroups&api_key=af3ac3bb7df2e70aa56921478847b6c2&user_id=62826388%40N02&format=rest)), but that attribute is [not documented](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPublicGroups.htm).

Comment: You're right 200_success. Also pool_count represents the number of photos in a group but the method from the group class getPhotoCount returns 0.

Comment: Ah yes you're right too rolfl. Will update that in my code, and review your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of things going on here, but it boils down to [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

I am going to take a stab at some guessing here, but I expect my numbers to be in the right ballparks. Your code does:

- Collection groupNames = people.getPublicGroups(userID);
- For each Group:

  - you connect to flickr
  - you download the data
  - you parse it
  - you write-to-file.

Here are things that you are doing slower than necessary:

1. you are parsing the same URL many times (as many times as you have groups to process), as the URL does not change inside the loop. If you process it once outside the loop, you will get the same results.
2. Is you file output buffered?
3. Do you need to `doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();` ?

Now, as for the real application of Amdahl's law, and, assuming the URL is wrong that you are processing (and that there should be 1 URL per group), you should: *run things in parallel*.

Consider something like:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(....);
....
LinkedList<Future<String>> futureops = new LinkedList<>();

while (...) {
    futureops.add(service.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
        public String call() throws IOException {
            // ****** Will need to probably do this as a separate class to get  *****
            // ****** it to compile right, or use `final` judiciously.          *****
            DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder b = f.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = b.parse(urlString);

            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("group");
            Node n = items.item(poolCounter);
            Element e = (Element) n;

            //get total photos in group
            String numberOfPhotos = e.getAttribute("pool_count");
            //get members in the group
            int numberOfMembers = gInfo.getMembers();       
            return "\t" + name + " " + numberOfPhotos + " photos" + ", " + numberOfMembers + " members";         
        }
    });

    while (!futureops.isEmpty()) {
        String result = futureops.removeFirst();
        file.writeFile(result);
        System.out.println(result);
        poolCounter++;
    }
}
```